# How to correctly expect an error to be thrown in Jest from inside a catch block of the function being spied on?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs

hitting a bit of roadblock on what seems to be something pretty straightforward:

Doing some testing for a user service, on a create method which is pretty basic:

```ts
create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
  const user = new User();
  user.email = createUserDto.email;

  return this.usersRepository.save(user)
    .catch((err: Record<string, unknown>) => {
      if (err.code == PSQL_ERR_CODES.unique_violation) {
        throw new DuplicateError(err);
      } else {
        throw new DatabaseError(err);
      }
    });
}
```

Where I'm checking unique violations, so if the same email is used twice, i get a DB error, which is then catched by the catch block. If the catch block grabs any other type of DB error, it should throw a Database error instead of a duplicate error (these 2 types of errors are custom types which are then handled by a global interceptor, but I digress)

I'm building a test to indeed verify that when the error that is caught has a specific code, the corresponding type of error is thrown. For that i have setup my tests as follows (exactly as the Jest [Docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tothrowerror) explain):

```js
it('should throw database error on other errors', async () => {
  jest.spyOn(repo, 'save').mockRejectedValue({
    code: 'unexpected_code'
  });
  expect(() => {
    service.create(new_user_dto);
  }).toThrowError(DatabaseError);
});
```

the `new_user_dto` I setup in a before and shouldn't be the issue.

debugging along the test, shows that indeed in the create function it's dropping into the catch block, with the correct object as the error `{ code: 'unexpected_code}`.
Yet I'm getting an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: [object Object]` which I can't figure out where is coming from. and most importantly the test is failing saying it did not throw

For the life of me I can't find the correct way to get this to work, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your code doesn't throw an error but returns a failed promise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like [@known-as-bmf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6548802/known-as-bmf) said, `create` returns a `Promise`, so you can't assert using `toThrowError` (which works only for synced assertion).

In order to test a rejected Promise, you should use [`rejects`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous#resolves--rejects), like this:

```js
await expect(create()).rejects.toEqual({
  code: "unexpected_code"
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-frog-uh9q3?file=/src/index.test.js:214-288

Alternatively, you can wrap the call in the test with `try/catch` and in the catch to `expect` the error to be equal to the error object.

```js
try {
  await create();
} catch (e) {
  expect(e).toEqual({
    code: "unexpected_code"
  });
}
```

[source](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous#asyncawait) (There are more examples)

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I didn't check for async as an issue. Apprecite the second alternative with the try catch, actually helps drive the point home pretty well

Comment: Wouldn't the last example still pass even if nothing is thrown??

Comment: @PitiOngmongkolkul yes, that was why I added `assert.fail('should throw exception');` after the testing line. Not sure how correct that is...

Comment: When I tried the first example I got test failure because the error is not an object - so it will not match toEqual any object you pass ?

Comment: @IanGrainger can you create a codesondbox that demonstrate your case?

Comment: TBH I had a different problem to the original asker. If you are using code which might run `throw new Error(` you can't expect it to ever `toEqual(object)`. But the code in this question does that. So this answer is fine. The question is just a bit weird compared to my code! ;)